# In OS X Server.app, what's the number in the app icon?

Tags: server.app

I have Server.app on 10.7, and when I start it, I get the neverending beachball, and in the Dock, the Server.app's icon has a red number in it, which is continuously increasing.

What's the number mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the number of alerts you have. There are several things that can prompt it to show alerts in Server.app, such as software updates available for the server, a volume unplugged unexpectedly, etc.